# Use cocoa touch Framework project in multiple apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode8

I had two ios apps with a lot of redundand code, so i decided to extract this code to a shared cocoa touch framework and added this frameworks  projectfile following [RayWenderlichs tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial) .
I also read the Apples [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-DontLinkElementID_3) but I am not able to solve my problem.

**State Now:**

 The both apps work fine with the added framework.

**My Problem:**
I can't build both apps with target ***Generic iOS Device*** ,only real device target or a simulator.
But both apps were able to build ***Generic iOS Device*** before adding the framework projects.

This is the output I get, trying to build with target ***Generic iOS Device***:

**Wished behaviour:**
I'd wish the app and framework behave just like a simple project lib in C# or Java. 
I don't understand why this error happens.

```
Showing Recent Issues
Ld /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VISUSDisplay.build/Debug-iphoneos/VISUSDisplay.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VISUSRemote normal armv7
    cd "/Users/dkronenberger/Documents/gitRepo/Mobile/VISUS/VISUS Display"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/dkronenberger/Documents/gitRepo/Mobile/VISUS/VISUS\ Display -F/Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Volumes/SoftwaresAndMedia/Adnan\ Projects/VISUS\ Project/Visus/Visus -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/dkronenberger/Documents/gitRepo/Mobile/VISUS/VISUS\ Display -filelist /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VISUSDisplay.build/Debug-iphoneos/VISUSDisplay.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VISUSRemote.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VISUSDisplay.build/Debug-iphoneos/VISUSDisplay.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VISUSRemote_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lz -lstdc++ -framework GameKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework CFNetwork /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ConnectionManager.framework/ConnectionManager -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreText -framework QuartzCore -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VISUSDisplay.build/Debug-iphoneos/VISUSDisplay.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VISUSRemote_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VISUSDisplay.build/Debug-iphoneos/VISUSDisplay.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VISUSRemote

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/SoftwaresAndMedia/Afelde Projects/VISUS Project/Visus/Visus'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ConnectionManager.framework/ConnectionManager, file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/dkronenberger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VISUSDisplay-cwapquipviigpndwwktvfnqurbsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ConnectionManager.framework/ConnectionManager
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConnectionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT:**
I already checked the architecture validation
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your framework `ConnectionManager.framework` has not been configured to compile code for the `armv7` architecture.

You may try to change the configuration settings of the `ConnectionManager`  target:

- Check that `Valid Architectures` contains all the variants: `arm64`, `armv7` and `armv7s`
- Try to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` for `Debug` and `Relase` if it does not still work.

Comment: I already checked both points before, this doesn't seem to be the problem, I added a Screenshot

Comment: Did you check it also for your main (non framework) project? What happens if you use "Archive" instead of "Build"?

Comment: I changed as you suggested, but now I get the same error with othder architecture: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConnectionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Comment: Did you try to clean the `DerivedData` folder and retry? Can you share the code?

Comment: Yes I tried, but get still the same Error, unfortunately I can't share, it's a CustomerProject :-/ any other Ideas ?

Comment: Additional info: If I set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` in Main Project, then I am not even able to build a device target any longer

Comment: May be revert `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes` in the main project and add `i386` inside the `Valid Architectures ` along with the others

Comment: No it also doesn't help, I still got the same Error with other Architecture Values, this Error drives me Crazy

Comment: It will be hard to provide further help without having access to the source code :( In case you find a solution, feel free to update your post to share it.